# MS Access ODBC call failed Query timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, timeout

All I'm trying to do is create 4 linked tables to 4 views in a sql database. 3 of them work fine, the other one gives me this error when I try to open it. It does take a long time to open it from sql mgmt studio (almost 3 mins). Searching online I can only find where people suggest changing the timeout property from design view, but when I open the linked table in design view there is no timeout property to be found. I can only see that when I open an actual query. I have already increased the timeout property in the registry for QueryTimeout to 5mins, yet I still get the timeout error after 60 secs. Hopefully I am making sense to someone :) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12):

You can set the timeout in your ADO connection object, or in the Access database options. Here's a screenshot from Access 2013. Look for the OLE/DDE timeout under the Client Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi another place to change the timeout is at the property sheet in case the one above didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW8tq.png)